How to access user-defined claims in a custom Keycloak protocol mapper?
Goal / Context
I have a workflow in which information about my users is scattered between my client, Keycloak, and an internal database.
Based on a given claim_token, I want to perform a lookup to further enrich identity tokens with custom claims.
The workflow is roughly as follows:

a request for a token is performed
a request to add information to the token (uma-ticket) is provided
a token with authentication, enriched data from the customer, lookup data from internal systems is assembled


sequenceDiagram
    actor Customer
    participant Keycloak
    participant Plugin
    participant Biz Logic
    
    Customer ->> Keycloak: identity?
    Keycloak ->> Customer: identity
    Customer ->> Keycloak: identity + claim_token (uma-ticket)
    Keycloak ->> Plugin: intercept token creation
    Plugin ->> Biz Logic: Query `department` and `shoe_size` claims
    Biz Logic ->> Plugin: {"departments": [71, 904]}
    Plugin ->> Plugin: add "departments" claim to token
    Plugin ->> Keycloak: final token
    Keycloak ->> Customer: identity with own + mapped claims

Example flow / what has been tried?
POST http://my-keycloak-instance/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=my-client
&client_secret=super-secret
&grant_type=password
&scope=openid
&username=a-username
&password=a-password

Then we add some claim_token information (that is only known to the client) to it:
POST http://my-keycloak-instance/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer {{ token_from_above_response }}
accept: application/json

client_id=my-client
&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket
&claim_token={{ to_jwt({department: ["sales", "accounting"], shoe_size: [36]}) }}
&claim_token_format=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt
&audience=an-audience

At this stage, I'd like a custom protocol mapper to use information that is given in claim_token to perform a third-party API call and and create a custom claim, for example: departments: [71, 904].
I implemented a custom protocol mapper such as follows (pseudo-code: nullability has been accounted for in my final code):
public class MapCustomUserClaimsToBusinessLogicGeneratedClaims
  extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper
  implements
    OIDCAccessTokenMapper,
    OIDCIDTokenMapper,
    UserInfoTokenMapper {
    // <SNIP>

  @Override
  public AccessToken transformAccessToken(
    AccessToken token,
    ProtocolMapperModel mappingModel,
    KeycloakSession keycloakSession,
    UserSessionModel userSession,
    ClientSessionContext clientSessionCtx
  ) {
    token.getOtherClaims()
      .put("departments", someBusinessLogic(
        token // ignore nullability/safety here: this is for making an example
          .getAuthorization()
          .getPermissions()
          .stream()
          .findFirst()
          .get()
          .getClaims()
      ));
    return token;
  }
}

What doesn't work?
To my surprise, token.getAuthorization() is always null: this seems to be because custom protocol mappers are executed before authorization is evaluated.
This behavior is visible in these very lines, where the TokenManager is responsible for running the various protocol mappers (under the hood):
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/12732333c80db8478aa70556c62e3f71ede44cbd/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/authorization/AuthorizationTokenService.java#L357-L365
The question
How do I access the information that is in claim_token (in the request) or in authorization (in the produced token) from within a custom protocol mapper?
Possible workaround?
While looking for solutions, I found that with Keycloak 25.0.2 (current latest stable release), it is possible to extract the claim_token from the current request from within the protocol mapper:
  keycloakSession
    .getContext()
    .getHttpRequest()
    .getDecodedFormParameters()

The above seems quite wrong on many levels, but it is an usable workaround until a cleaner approach comes up.
